# Prime number checker returns any number as a prime. C

Tags: c, if-statement, primes

This program is supposed to print every number that is not prime from 3 to 100.
But it acts like it doesn’t interpret well the last if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int i,k;
    int flag;
    for (i=3; i<100; i++) {
        for (k=2; k<=i/2; k++) {
            if (i%k == 0) {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag==0) {
            printf("not prime : %d\n",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Whats the matter? It should print i only if flag was equal to 0. I get printed all the numbers from 3 to 100 as not primes.

Im confused.

Comment: setting `flag` to zero is a one-way street in your program: you never set it back to `1`. Fixing this will get your program running.

Comment: You probably have to unset the flag once you print a number.

Comment: You really need to learn how to **use the debugger**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `flag` to a non-zero value:

```
for (i = 3; i < 100; i++){
    flag = 1;
    for(k = 2; k <= i/2; ++k){
        if(i % k == 0) { 
            flag = 0; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag==0)  { printf("not prime : %d\n",i); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int i,k;
    // int flag;
    for (i=3; i<100; i++){ 
            for (k=2; k<i; k++){ // note this loop
                    if(i%k == 0) break;
            }
            if (k!=i)  { printf(" not prime : %d\n",i); }
    }
}
```

In this method, When `if(i%k == 0)` is true, loop will `break`. At that time, `i` is dividable by any number between `i` and `k`. So if any number dividable by 1 and other then that number, that is not a prime number.

Comment: While this works, it doesn't explain _why_ it works. Also, `flag` is now unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

The flag is never set to anything but zero. So it may be zero from the beginning, and it definitely will be zero from the moment you set it to zero until the end of the program.
What you need to do is set it to nonzero before the "prime-finding" (inner) loop.